# Wordpress 301 permanent redirect with exceptions

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to set a permanent redirect whenever someone visits *myoldsite.com* or its subpages to *mynewsite.com*  like that:

> visit *myoldsite.com* go to *mynewsite.com*
>
> visit *myoldsite.com/subpage* go to *mynewsite.com* (and NOT
>   *mynewsite.com/subpage*)

I would also like to make exceptions to the above for *wp-admin* and *wp-login* subpages. I don't have server access to *myoldsite* Wordpress installation, so I can edit *.htaccess* file only through a Wordpress plugin. I would also like to make an exception for *.htaccess* if possible, in order to be able to reedit *.htaccess* via my 'Wordpress .htaccess plugin' once the redirect is done, so I can have the power to revert things back to default if necessary.

My .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

In your htaccess plugin editor, add the following line in your rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mynewsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your suggestion would redirect everything and I would lost access to wp-admin.

Comment: You gonna need to give more details than "it doesn't work". It's a pretty straightforward rule, so if it doesn't work you probably have some other problem - like your htaccess plugin editor add this rule after some others so it get bypassed.

Comment: Ok, more specific: It redirects when I go to _myoldsite.com/wp-admin_. If I'm already logged in, I can navigate the admin area, but I can't logout.

Comment: Now it just redirects when visiting the homepage, but not when visiting subpages. It just limits the design, but no redirect. It somehow limits the admin area, too. It's possible to navigate the admin area, but some functions are disabled.

Comment: You gonna need to isolate any url that you don't want to redirect and are not in wp-admin and make conditions for them, like I did for _wp-login.php_.

Comment: I can't put your code to work. It redirects me no matter what. Where exactly shall I add your code? I added my .htacces file in the opening post.